# startIntent with documents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, documents, quickoffice

I have a problem, I have this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));

        intent.setType("application/*");
        startNewActivity(intent);
```

I opened Documents but throws me an error , saying Documents has closed unexpectedly.

But on the other hand , if I navigate to the file location and I open it, Documents, opens me perfectly .

I trace capturing the whole I find this phone .

> E/CAKEMIX_CRASHED﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs/com.qo.android.quickoffice.QuickofficeDispatcher}:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.quickoffice.android/com.google.android.apps.docs.quickoffice.HomeActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

all help as welcome.

THX

Comment: "_have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?_" Did you declare that activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: What do the `startNewActivity()` do?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. 

public void startNewActivity(Intent intent) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: No, i dont declare Quickoffice in my manifest :S

Comment: No, i dont declare Quickoffice in my manifest :S

And i dont know how do that, but i think it's not that.

P.S.- I tried declaring the action view in the manifest but it did not work

<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />